# Intellij IDEA automatically excluding folder named 'results' and can't re-include

Tags: intellij-idea

I have Intellij IDEA v15.0 Build #IU-143.381.

I have a project to do image processing, so I created a folder named 'results' to put the resulting images. It was immediately shown as being 'excluded'. I went to the File->Project Structure->Modules menu and saw the file structure under my content root. I clicked on the 'results' folder and the toggle at the top said it was excluded:
[image]

However, it wasn't listed with the other excluded folders in the right sidebar, and I could not click on the excluded button to toggle off the exclusion.

I tried moving all the files in 'results' into a new directory called 'results2', and it was not automatically excluded. However, when I deleted the 'results' directory and renamed 'results2' as 'results', it was excluded again.

Is there something special about a directory named 'results'? If so, how can I change the default setting that causes it to be excluded?

Answer (score 1):

Folder exclusions are listed in the .iml file of your project, under a 'content' tag. Removing 'results' from there should solve the problem.

You can find the .iml file in the home directory of your project.

Comment: You helped point me in the right direction. It wasn't listed in the iml file, but in .idea/misc.xml, there was a <output> tag that pointed to the results folder.  I got rid of that line, closed and reopened the project, and that worked.